# To find the filename who use the particular account name in unix server

Tags: unix, grep, find

I have to prepare one sheet like below. I want to find those files where we have used EDW account. But when I am using find command then it is returning everything which contains the word EDW. Even it returns those file don't have permission & can't open etc (printing unnecessary line).

I only need to print those file using the account name EDW,GDW etc with path name & file name. So that I can prepare one sheet as below.

AccountName          Server                  Path name    File name

XCM                                  uk0300uv550                        /home/super/MKBP/scripts/xtc/rap                     proc_build.sql

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Add in post what you have tried ?

Comment: find . -exec grep "EDW" {} /dev/null \;
find . -exec grep -s "EDW" '{}' \; -print

Comment: find . -exec grep -i "EDW" {} /dev/null \; > EDW_15062016.txt

Comment: find . -type f -exec grep "EDW" /dev/null {} +

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a list with all files where "EDW" occurs?  Try `-l` to **list** just the filenames and `-r` to grep **recursively**:

```bash
echo "Text with EDW inside." > file.txt
grep -lr EDW .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to find files that are **owned** by a specific **user/group**, you could simply use:

```
find /path/ -user EDW -group EDW
```

If you would like to find only files that are both owned by your user and contain the word EDW in their name you could:

```
find /path/ -user EDW -name "*EDW*"
```